# Why won't Facebook accept the URL of my website in the About section of my Facebook page?

Tags: facebook, web-testing

We are a legitimate company with an established website, but when I go to enter our website: https://www.valobasargolpo.com  into the appropriate field in our About section on our Facebook page, it responds with an error message: "The website URL you provided is invalid. Please enter a correct URL and try again."

Why is this happening?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.valobasargolpo.com%2F says, _“We can't review this website because the content doesn't meet our Community Standards. If you think this is a mistake, please let us know.”_ - which basically means, Facebook has blocked your domain, because they think it is spam or a scam. The form to report this as a wrongful block can be found right there in the message, but don’t expect immediate results - it will probably take a couple of reports by different people, before they look into the matter,